# Verify that $x$ is a fixed point

Tags: roots, fixed-point-theorems

Given the function $f(x) = {-x^4 \over 4} + x^3 -4x + 4$ I have graphically localized two  roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (with $\alpha < \beta$). After analyzing them with Newton's algorithm I'm given the fixed point equation $g(x) = x - {f(x) \over m}$ with $m \ne 0$ and I'm asked to verify that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed points for $g$.

How can I verify that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are fixed points of $g$ if I don't have the exact root points to test $g(x) = x$?

Comment: By the definition of $g$ you have that $g(x)=x \iff f(x)=0\,$.

Comment: Oh, you mean that I just need to prove that $g(x)=x \iff f(x) = 0$ because only when $f(x)=0$ then $g(x) = x$ (with $f(x)=0$ then the term ${f(x) \over m}$ nullifies and only $g(x)=x$ remains).I didn't think about that...thanks!

Comment: Right, that's all.

Comment: A LOT easier that what I thought! Thanks! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to post a self-answer yourself, and I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks you once again then! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @dxiv pointed out, it's really straight forward.
$g(x)=x$ only when the term ${f(x) \over m} = 0$ which is only when $f(x) = 0$ and, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $f(x)$, when $x=\alpha$ or $x=\beta$ the term $f(x)\over m$ nullifies, resulting whith $g(x)=x$